# Washing greasy/contaminated construction textiles

Tags: safety, cleaning, chemicals

I'm collecting greasy/contaminated construction textiles (shirts, rags etc) in a dedicated bucket and not with general laundry. Is there a recommended **general** (meaning it works with most types of contaminants) treatment for such textiles before they are safe to put in a regular washer? Like soak it in some chemical to release the gunk.

Answer (score 2):

I would wash them in a bucket or tub with plenty of detergent and water as hot as the garments can take. Then rinse them with a hose onto grass or soil. Check to see if grease is removed before putting in the regular washer.

Answer (score 1):

I use simple green when I get really greasy I do adigitate it and dump it prior to putting in the washing machine but the simple green works well at breaking down the grease and simple green is non hazardous.